# Make one button do two different things

Tags: android, libgdx

What Im trying to implement is to have one of my buttons draw an image on the screen on click, but then I need to same button to dispose()/clear() the image when pressed again! I´ve managed this before, but I can´t remember how it´s done.

```
btnShare.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

                stage.addActor(btnFB);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the button was clicked by setting a certain `Boolean clicked = false;` to true and false like this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clicked) {
                clear();
                clicked = false;
            }
            else {
                draw();
                clicked = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you good sir. I forgot to use "else", instead I just used if within an if.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `clickListener` with `boolean` value. When value if `false` draw an image. if value is `true`- clear image.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that imageView is visible

```
if(view.isVisiable){
      // do this
 }
else{
     // do this
     }
```